# retrieve name of calling script / Javascript in php

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Securing a remote ajax method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503469/securing-a-remote-ajax-method-call)

Is there a way to retrieve the name of the javascript file that called a php script from within the PHP code?

Unfortunately, since I have to call a PHP script from Javascript (for Google maps) on a webpage, this 'invites' to retrieve my data by just calling the PHP script by hand. Checking for the script/file that invoked the PHP script would bring at least some protection.

Comment: I'd consider using `POST` in the call and sending some (not secret because it is via JavaScript) session key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a session variable with some random value on the server when your page is opened, and add that variable in the query string to your php script.

Then in your javascript-called php script, you start the session and check the session variable against the query one.